# HTML5/Canvas onDrop event isn't firing? 

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm playing with file upload, drag and drop, and canvas, but for some reason the ondrop function never seems to run, here's the fiddle I'm working in: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/E4yRv/

the relevant code is :

```
canvas.ondrop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
            reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var img = new Image(),
                imgStr = event.target.result;
            state.innerHTML += ' Image Uploaded: <a href="' +
                imgStr + '" target="_blank">view image</a><br />';
            img.src = event.target.result;
            img.onload = function(event) {
                context.height = canvas.height = this.height;
                context.width = canvas.width = this.width;
                context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                state.innerHTML += ' Canvas Loaded: <a href="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" target="_blank">view canvas</a><br />';
            };
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return false;
    };
```

why doesn't this event fire? I've tried it in firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to get the drop event to fire at all you need to have an `ondragover` function:

```
canvas.ondragover = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

If you try to drag your cat picture into the canvas it'll still not work, this error is reported in the Firefox console:

```
[04:16:42.298] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMFileReader.readAsDataURL]"  nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame :: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 57"  data: no]
```

However it will work if you [drag an image from your desktop](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/E4yRv/30/).  I think for images in the page you should use regular DOM access methods, the File API is only needed for external files dragged into the browser.

Comment: it works, awesome! I didn't expect the cat to work with the file API, I was just using it to test the dragging since images from my desktop kept opening in-browser.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, robertc's answer is how browsers continue to behave, you have to have an `ondragover` function set.

But to expand on it slightly, the function must return `false` and not `true` or `undefined`-- no-op functions will return `undefined`. It doesn't seem to matter whether you prevent default, the ondrop event handler will trigger. You will want a preventDefault in the ondrop function, otherwise the file will be immediately downloaded to your browser's default download folder:

```js
document.getElementById('drop-zone').ondragover = function(e) {
  return false;
}

document.getElementById('drop-zone').ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('ondrop', e);
}
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  border: solid;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop-zone">Drop zone</div>
```